# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, time, module

It works if I type `if int(hour) >= 19:` but I would like it to work with something similar to this line `if current_time >= exit_time:`

```
import time    

current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')    

exit_time = ('19:00:00','%H:%M:%S')    
hour = time.strftime('%H')     
minute = time.strftime('%M')    
second = time.strftime('%S')    

if current_time >= exit_time:    
    print ("It's time to go home")     
else:    
    print ("{} hours, {} minutes and {} seconds to go home".format(18-int(hour),
         59-int(minute), 59-int(second)))
```

Comment: `exit_time` is a tuple of two strings: `'19:00:00'` and `'%H:%M:%S'`. Is that what it is supposed to be?

Comment: Are you missing a `time` function call here `exit_time = ('19:00:00','%H:%M:%S')`?

Comment: You should use `time` or `datetime` objects from the `datetime` module instead of strings (or tuples).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're comparing `current_time` (which is a string) and `exit_time` (which is a tuple containing 2 strings).
Maybe try something like:

```
if current_time >= exit_time[0]:
    # your code
```

Since the first member of the tuple is probably what you want to compare to `current_time`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative to this is.

```
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=00)
exit_time = current_time.replace(hour=19, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)

if current_time >= exit_time:    
    print ("It's time to go home")     
else: 
    time_delta = (exit_time - current_time).total_seconds()
    hours_left = int(time_delta // 60 // 60)
    minutes_left = int(time_delta // 60) - hours_left*60
    seconds_left = int(time_delta) - hours_left*3600 - minutes_left*60
    
    print ("{} hours, {} minutes and {} seconds to go home".format(hours_left,
         minutes_left, seconds_left))
```